# C++ concept for read and writable containers with const safety while writing

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I would like to create a `concept` which allows me to define a single function for each `read` and `write` from/to a data container. The data container should have a `.data()` and a `.size()` methods, so that the size can be checked before reading/writing.
Additionally, for the writing function, the datatype should be marked `const`, so that I cannot change the variable which is pointing to, or its content by mistake.

As example I would like to support datatypes like `std::vector` and if possible `std::span` if I only have the pointer and the size separated.

To check if a container has both methods, I came up with

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept HasDataAndSize =
    requires(T t) { t.size(); } && requires(T t) { t.data(); } &&
    requires(T t) { std::is_same<decltype(t.size()), std::size_t>::value; } &&
    requires(T t) { std::is_pointer<decltype(t.data())>::value; };
```

The problem is, if I create a function

```cpp
template<HasDataAndSize T> void write(const T& data)
```

the data is writable for a `std::span` object.

Additionally, if I create a reading function

```cpp
template<HasDataAndSize T> void read(T read)
```

`std::span` works, however containers like `std::vector` are copied and the change accessible outside  the function. If I use a `T &` `std::vector` works, but I cannot use `std::span<>` from a temporary like `read(std::span{data_ptr, data_size})`

Currently I think I only can allow containers, which do not allow changing the ptr inside it, like `std::span` can. However, my concept still lets `std::span` through, and I don't know how to stop it.

Or is there a better solution? / reason why I should use another design?

I created a small example to play around with: https://godbolt.org/z/nT7jWve91

To clarify, I am writing on a library which, among other things, has to write data from different data containers into a file or read the content from the file into the data.

Comment: I guess the simplest solution would be to only define `read(T* data, size_t size)` and `write(const T * const data, size_t size), but I still would be interested if it is possible with concepts.

Comment: Is there some reason why you keep repeating `requires(T t)`? You know you can have multiple clauses under there, right? Also, why are you not using `contiguous_range`?

Comment: I don't quite understand. Is `write` suppose to write *to* the container? Is `read` supposed to read *from* the container? Or is something else going on? Because I can't understand why you want `read` to take the container by value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with this:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept HasDataAndSize =
    requires(T t) { t.size(); } && requires(T t) { t.data(); } &&
    requires(T t) { std::is_same<decltype(t.size()), std::size_t>::value; } &&
    requires(T t) { std::is_pointer<decltype(t.data())>::value; };
```

First and foremost, there is no need to separate everything into its own requires-expression, this adds a lot of syntax with no benefit. This is equivalent to:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept HasDataAndSize =
    requires(T t) {
        t.size();
        t.data();
        std::is_same<decltype(t.size()), std::size_t>::value; // (1)
        std::is_pointer<decltype(t.data())>::value;           // (2)
    };
```

Next, the lines marked `(1)` and `(2)` above don't... actually do what you think they do. Indeed, they don't do anything at all. What you're checking is that the *expression* `std::is_same<T, U>::value` is a valid expression - which of course it is, regardless of `T` and `U`. You're not actually checking that the types are the same.

In order to do that, you need to either prefix the expression with `requires` or use the compound requirement syntax:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept HasDataAndSize =
    requires(T t) {
        // t.size() needs to be size_t
        { t.size() } -> std::same_as<size_t>;

        // t.data() needs to be valid and have pointer type
        t.data();
        requires std::is_pointer_v<decltype(t.data())>;
    };
```

---

Once we get there, the you have this other problem

```cpp
template<HasDataAndSize T> void write(const T& data)
```

This is checking that `T` has `data()` and `size()`, but that's not really the relevant question here, since `data` isn't a `T`, it's a `T const`. Here, you need to do:

```cpp
template <class T>
    requires HasDataAndSize<T const>
void write(const T& data)
```

or introduce a helper concept:

```cpp
template <class T> concept HasConstDataAndSize = HasDataAndSize<T const>;
template<HasConstDataAndSize T> void write(const T& data)
```

or use a forwarding reference (which will ensure that `T` is deduced in a way that's useful for concepts):

```cpp
template<HasDataAndSize T> void write(T&& data)
```

---

Lastly, this is more of an API issue, but it's probably better to eschew this entirely and just write:

```cpp
void write(std::span<std::byte> );
void read(std::span<std::byte const> );
```

Although generally I don't really understand what the API here is supposed to do.

Comment: Thank you very much. I added a sentence to clarify the purpose behind my functions.
I am just getting familiar with the features of C++20 and with your answer I was able to understand the principle behind it.